# Decoding JSON Web Tokens in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, base64, jwt

trying to decode a JWT payload in Swift and having a really difficult time

```
static func decodePayload(tokenstr: String) {

    //splitting JWT to extract payload
    let arr = split(tokenstr) {$0 == "."}

    //base64 encoded string i want to decode
    let base64String = arr[1] as String
    println(base64String) //eyJleHAiOjE0MjY4MjIxNjMsImlkIjoiNTUwYjA3NzM4ODk1NjAwZTk5MDAwMDAxIn0

    //attempting to convert base64 string to nsdata 
    let nsdata: NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    //decoding fails because nsdata unwraps as nil
    let base64Decoded: NSString = NSString(data: nsdata!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!


}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
eyJleHAiOjE0MjY4MjIxNjMsImlkIjoiNTUwYjA3NzM4ODk1NjAwZTk5MDAwMDAxIn0
```

is not a valid Base64 encoded string because its length
is not a multiple of 4. Some Base64 decoder tolerate this error, but
the `NSData` methods don't.

So this is actually an error on the server side creating the
Base64 encoded string. If necessary, you can fix it in your app
 by adding the required padding with `=` characters (code updated for Swift 2):

```
var base64String = arr[1] as String
if base64String.characters.count % 4 != 0 {
    let padlen = 4 - base64String.characters.count % 4
    base64String += String(count: padlen, repeatedValue: Character("="))
}
```

And now the decoding works as expected:

```
if let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: []),
    let str = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    print(str) // {"exp":1426822163,"id":"550b07738895600e99000001"}
}
```

---

**Swift 4:**

```
var base64String = "eyJleHAiOjE0MjY4MjIxNjMsImlkIjoiNTUwYjA3NzM4ODk1NjAwZTk5MDAwMDAxIn0"

if base64String.count % 4 != 0 {
    let padlen = 4 - base64String.count % 4
    base64String.append(contentsOf: repeatElement("=", count: padlen))
}

if let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) ,
    let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(str) // {"exp":1426822163,"id":"550b07738895600e99000001"}
}
```

Comment: where exactly should jwt tokens be stored as best practice? I've been thinking that it should be stored into keychain along with user name and password.

Comment: @user805981: I actually don't know anything about jwt tokens. But yes, sensitive data like passwords should be stored in the Keychain.

Comment: Thanks.  Concerning keychains. How many keychain dictionaries is the keychain able to store per app? Is it infinite or one password keychain per app?

Comment: @MartinR Can you point me to the reference for this "not a valid Base64 encoded string because its length is not a multiple of 4"?

Comment: See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64: *“... the encoded output must have padding added so that its length is a multiple of four.”*

Answer (score 4):

Above solution is working for me, I converted into swift3

Here you can find swift3 code

```
var base64Str = arr[1] as String
if base64Str.characters.count % 4 != 0 {
    let padlen = 4 - base64Str.characters.count % 4      
    base64Str += String(repeating: "=", count: padlen)
}

if let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64Str, options: []),
    let str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        print(str)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 4 as below:

```
if let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String, options: []),
        let str = String(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        print(str) // {"exp":1426822163,"id":"550b07738895600e99000001"}
    }
```

Comment: In Swift 4 it's better to use Data than NSData (and way better to use Data than to cast NSData to Data). And *anyway*, update for Swift 3+ has already been given by @raju-abe in their answer. Please do not post duplicate/incomplete content.