# NSDataBase64DecodingOptions is returning nil value

Tags: json, swift, base64, decode

I am trying to parse base64 type into imageData. But my NSDataBase64DecodingOptions returns nil. I printed decodedData and it is nil. My code is here

```
var base64String = arrayText["auto_type_android_img"] as String

println("basestring64 is \(base64String)")

let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

println("base string is: \(decodedData)")
if let decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!) {

    imageTypeOfCar?.image = decodedImage
}
```

Comment: That most probably means that the Base64 string is not valid. Have you tested it in some online Base64 converter? Also NSData is strict about the required padding (length must be a multiple of 4), compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152706/decoding-json-web-tokens-in-swift.

Comment: Hello Martin, yes I tried and I got the picture from online converter...

Comment: Have you verified that the *length* of the Base64 string is a multiple of 4 ?

Comment: http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/

Comment: what do you mean saying length of multiple of 4?

Comment: I am not quite sure , do I need to include "data:image\/png;base64" into base64String?

Comment: No. The length of a Base64 string must be a multiple of 4 (e.g. 4, 8, 12, ..., 100, 104, 108, ...). Have a look at "Padding" in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64. The link from my first comment shows a possible workaround.

Comment: if countElements(base64String) % 4 != 0 {
                let padlen = 4 - countElements(base64String) % 4
                
                base64String += String(count: padlen, repeatedValue: Character("="))
            }

Comment: my JSOn is multiple of 4, I found script that adds "=" if it is not multiple of 4. However problem is not in the length!

Comment: Ok, it was just an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `base64String` is

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA......YII=
```

The initial `"data:image/png;base64,"` is *not* part of the Base64
encoding and must be removed before the string can be decoded:

```
if let range = base64String.rangeOfString("data:image/png;base64,", options: .AnchoredSearch)  {
    base64String.removeRange(range)
}
```

Then

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: nil)
if let decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!) {
    imageTypeOfCar?.image = decodedImage
}
```

succeeds and displays

[image]