# NSDataBase64DecodingOptions always returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, base64, decode, encode

There are a lot of similar questions but non of them helped me out so I just don't know what to do but ask. So this is how I encode a UIImage:

```
       let data: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageResized)!
       let base64String: NSString = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

and decoding (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438793/nsdatabase64decodingoptions-is-returning-nil-value)):

```
if let range = base64.rangeOfString("data:image/png;base64,", options: .AnchoredSearch)  {
                base64.removeRange(range)
            }
            let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            if let decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!) {
                self.imageList.append(decodedImage)
            }
```

But the app crashes when initializing decodedData and I can't figure out why. 
I checked my base64 string [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html) and it returns the picture.
Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
   if let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters){
        if(decodedData.length > 0){
            let imageDecodeData =  UIImage(data: decodedData)!
        }
        else{
            print("error")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line with `let decodedData` with:

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64, options: [])
```

And also make sure that your using correct variables:

```
// 1. This should be a variable if you're mutating it.
let base64String = data...

// 2. You should probably do this on your base64String
if let range = base64.rangeOfString(...)
```

Comment: if base64 is NSString, decodedData shows error - let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64 as String, options: [])

Comment: You don't need to cast it as `NSString`, see updated answer.

Comment: base64 is a variable and I am doing rangeOfString(), but my base64 string is valid before this range. I updated let decodedData as you suggested but with the same result